# Migrating from GitHub to GitLab

Tags: git, github, server, gitlab, repository

Recently I have migrated successfully my repository from GitHub to GitLab. However, I have my code running on a server using the cloned repository from GitHub that I have been pushing local changes to it. How can I start pushing local changes to the GitLab repo and pull changes on the server from the new migrated repo on GitLab keeping the same project running on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit confused, but if I understood you should update the `origin` remote on your application server by `git remote set-url origin <GITLAB_URI>`.

Regards.